# VB6 user requested cancel of current operation Oracle error

Tags: oracle, vb6

I'm currently troubleshooting a VB6 application that sporadically comes up with the following error:
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

All of the research I've done on this error states that it is either an actual request for cancellation by the user or a timeout. It can't be a request for cancellation because the input is coming in from an automated source, so it must be a timeout. One thing I read online was to un-check the query timeout checkbox in the DSN configuration box but my program uses a DSN-less connection to the database, which is an Oracle 10g database.

There are several queries in this program but it always fails on one query in particular, however I can't reproduce the error in a test environment using all of the same input to the program that caused the error in the first place.

A co-worker of mine suggested doing a rollback after each query even though the queries are read only because some kind of buffer might be getting filled up or something of the like, but this didn't work. At this point I don't even know how to continue troubleshooting it because I can't reproduce the error. If someone could give me any idea of what is going on and how to fix the problem I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What connection string are you using and are you able to post the code that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

All of the options that you can choose when setting up a DSN can be specified in the connection string if you are using a DSN-less connection.  If you want to disable query timeouts, you would add

```
QTO=F
```

to the connection string.  So your new connection string would be something like

```
DRIVER={Oracle ODBC Driver};UID=Kotzwinkle;PWD=whatever;DBQ=instl_alias;QTO=F;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to implement it. One concern though, with the query timeout being turned off, don't I now have to worry about the query hanging?

Comment: @BrendonDavies - If your application allows users to issue ad hoc SQL statements, yes, you would need to worry about people generating runaway queries.  There are a number of ways that can be mitigated on the back end-- Resource Manager, for example, or simply alerting the DBA to kill particularly long-running sessions.  If this is an application that you are building, though, presumably you can design and build the application to prevent queries from hanging.

Comment: This is an application that runs 24/7 and we get "transactions" that are processed by this program from other companies any time of day or night. I just checked and turning off the query timeout resulted in a bunch of hanging instances of the program. The task manager showed 50+ hung processes of the same name of the program, so I don't think turning off the query timeout option is going to be viable for my situation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @BrendonDavies - If you get transactions that regularly generate SQL statements that would run longer than you want, the two options would be to allow those transactions to continue running (possibly eventually killing them on the back end) or using query timeouts to kill them from the front end.  It sounds like you're saying that the current behavior of periodic "ORA-01013" errors is preferable to letting those queries run. If that's the case, then there is no problem to solve. Figuring out why the sessions were "hung" and fixing the application would also seem reasonable.